# How do I retrieve the indexes in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the code from this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge

It creates an array of objects based on specified spreadsheet data (getRowsData). Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by a normalized column name.

For an application different than email merge, I want to populate another sheet in the spreadsheet with the index names, how can I retrieve an array of the index values of the objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vocabulary you want to use here is "key", not "index", which would typically refer to the integer index of an array. To get the object keys, you can use the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method.

```js
const rowData = { 
  firstName: 'First',
  lastName: 'Last',
  emailAddress: 'first.last@example.com',
};

const keys = Object.keys(rowData);

console.log(keys); // [ "firstName", "lastName", "emailAddress" ]
```